# how to use an notification that when clicked on it only clear and does nothing else

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a question: I want make a notification in status bar. But when clicking on it, it just clears it and doesn't launch any intent. How can I do this?

```
Intent intent;
intent= new Intent(myclass.this, myclass.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(myclass.this, 0, intent, 0);
String body = "This is a test message";
String title = "test msg";
Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, body,System.currentTimeMillis());
n.setLatestEventInfo(myclass.this, title, body, pi);
n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;  
nm.notify(uniqueID, n);
```

With this code, when the notification raised and I click on it, the new intent will be created and shown. I don't want to create any new intent. Just clear the notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, null, PendingIntent. FLAG_ONE_SHOT) 
n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; // just like that teoRetik says
```

Comment: when i puss null value my app does not work on notification. give FORCE CLOSE

Comment: thank you vikram. i do this. it does not create intent (ok) but the notification does not be dismissed after click on it. it still show on notification bar always.

Comment: Did you set "FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL" too?

Comment: its done. thank you vikram. i didnt what @teoRETIK say well. when i fix it my code works ok.

Answer (score 1):

From the official documentation:

> To clear the status bar notification when the user selects it from the
>   notifications window, add the "FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL" flag to your
>   Notification. You can also clear it manually with cancel(int), passing
>   it the notification ID, or clear all your notifications with
>   cancelAll().

Comment: This is because you need to set it like that: `n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;`. Edited.

Comment: i set this flag with following code but this does not work still when i click on notification it create and lunch a new intent. code: n.defaults = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;